# Relativistic effects on charge

Tags: special-relativity, charge, inertial-frames

Does charge of the body gets affected by relativity or is constant in all frames of references?

Answer (score 1):

The Lorentz transformations affect position and time, not the charge.
Therefore, charge is invariant but the current (i.e. $q\mathbf v$) is not.

Comment: Does it imply that magnetic effects are relative?(because of is dependence on current)

Comment: @Nithish Yes, of course. Both magnetic and electric field are quantities that depend on the reference frame.

Comment: @Nithish Correct. Electric and magnetic fields convert to each other depending on the frame. They are temporal and spatial projections of the electromagnetic field. A static charge has no magnetic field. A charge moving close to the speed of light has almost no electric field.

Comment: @safesphere your wording is incorrect. The electromagnetic tensor is not invariant, it just transforms following the Lorentz transformations.

Comment: @AlessandroZunino: This answer could be improved by citing the experimental evidence, which basically comes from bounds on the net charge of atoms. BTW, it's perfectly correct to say that a tensor is invariant. People who prefer to describe it that way will say that the tensor is invariant, but its components depend on what coordinates you use to describe it.

Comment: @BenCrowell feel free to edit the answer if you want to improve it, just pay attention on which is the level of the OP. About the second matter: a quantity is called invariant if, after applying the Lorentz transformations, it is exactly the same. This is how the term is used in every reference I ever read.

Comment: @AlessandroZunino: *a quantity is called invariant if, after applying the Lorentz transformations, it is exactly the same.* Yes, and that's consistent with saying that the quantity stays exactly the same, while its components differ.

Answer (score 0):

That the charge of a body is constant in all frames of reference is proved in several textbooks.